# How can I remove test directories when deploying?

Tags: deployment, 10

When deploying Drupal, there are a lot of files in `test` directories, none of which are needed in a production environment. There's an ongoing issue to [Exclude test files from release packages](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3067979), but how can I get rid of the test files now?

Answer (score 1):

After trying to configure `drupal-core-vendor-hardening` to do this, I realized that it's too much of a pain to add each individual module.

So I wrote a simple bash script instead.

```
cd "$my_git_root"
# Delete Drupal test directories.
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89937
find . -type d -name tests -exec rm -rf {} +
# Delete testing and demo profiles.
find web/core/profiles -type d -name 'testing*' -exec rm -rf {} +
find web/core/profiles -type d -name 'nightwatch_testing' -exec rm -rf {} +
find web/core/profiles -type d -name 'demo_umami' -exec rm -rf {} +
# Delete README files.
find . -type f -name 'README*' -delete
find . -type f -name 'CHANGELOG*' -delete
# Delete patch records.
find . -type f -name 'PATCHES.txt' -delete
# Delete markdown files except licenses.
find web -type f -name "*.md" -not -name "LICENSE*" -delete
# Delete txt files except licenses.
find web -type f -name "*.txt" -not -name "LICENSE*" -not -name "COPYRIGHT*" -delete
```

Doing this, I managed to reduce my build size from 213 MB to 172 MB.

Answer (score 0):

[core-vendor-hardening](https://github.com/drupal/core-vendor-hardening) can clean up test files and any other directories you want.

The only downside is that you have to make an entry per module in composer.json.

```
"extra": {
    "drupal-core-vendor-hardening": {
        "drupal/core": ["tests","profiles/demo_umami"],
        "drupal/json_field": ["tests"]
    },
}
```

The above example also shows how to delete the umami profile-- you need to insert the directory path. So, if you want to delete `tests` from all modules of core, you are looking at a very extensive list.

Note: To actually delete the files after modifying `composer.json`, you can delete the relevant directory and then run `composer.install`.  If you change `composer.json` and then run `composer update`, the files will remain.